# On the definition of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, definitions

I remember once reading that "a continuous function can be loosely described as a function whose graph can be drawn without lifting the pen from the paper". We all know that this is not true. I was looking for a way to give a well defined concept of a "somewhat continuous" function from this idea. Of course it would be a totally different definition and not at all equivalent to continuity as we know, to not cause any confusion let's call it *p2p* and avoid the use of "continuous".

maybe:

**Definition:** *Let $f :  A \to B$ a function and $a \in A$. We say that $f$ is p2p at $a$ if there is a neighborhood $N_a$ of $a$ such that the graph of $f |_{N_a}$ is connected.*

Let's say that we restrict $A$ and $B$ to be locally connected topological spaces.

What can be done to improve this definition? What would be the consequences if we develop a theory with a concept like this in place of the usual continuity?

In summary, my question is, what is the best we can do to give a well defined concept of a "somewhat continuous" function that capture the physical idea of a pencil-to-paper graph?

Comment: This "partial graph connectivity ==> continuity" claim is false.

Comment: This is false even when $A=B=N_a=\mathbb R$.

Comment: The "continuity" in [This "partial graph connectivity ==> continuity" claim is false.] is the usual continuity?

Comment: Oh, do you mean concepts that are somewhat similar but not equivalent to continuity?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean with this question.

Comment: Every function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with *path-connected* graph is continuous. But since the definition of path connectedness requires the notion of a continuous function, this "definition" suffers from an infinite regress.

Comment: I am voting to close, because your definition does not give continuity.

Comment: @RobertFurber correct, my first thought was about localy path-connected graphs but that depends on the definition of continuity.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Perhaps I should edit my question because I did not want to give a definition equivalent to continuity as we know, I even said that *We all know that this is not true*. It caused a misunderstanding and that is my fault. My question is, what is the best we can do to give a well defined concept of a "somewhat continuous" function that capture the physical idea of a pencil-to-paper graph? It would be a totally different definition and not at all equivalent to the what we are used to.

Answer (score 7):

The function $f$, defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\sin\frac1x$ if $x\neq0$, is not continuous at $0$, but its graph is connected over every open interval that contains $0$.
With a bit of work, shifting $f$ around and scaling it, you can create a function that exhibits this behaviour at every rational number.

Comment: That was about the simplest of examples that I had in my mind when commenting on OP post.

Comment: There are functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(U)=\mathbb{R}$ for every nonempty open set $U$, so that's also a pretty discontinous counterexample

Comment: @WlodAA I do not see any examples in your comments. You just said it is fale when $A=B=N_a=\mathbb{R}$. That is not an example.

Comment: What you describe is essentially Sierpinski's "punctiform connected graph" where punctiform = no compact connected subset. The OP may want to see the dissertation here: https://www.apronus.com/static/MRWojcikPhD.pdf, which is a fairy complete study of this type of thing.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz, I said ***in my mind***. (Right, of course, u'r not a reader of my mind, and let's keep it this way).

Comment: Are there any concrete examples in constructive real analysis? In constructive mathematics, the given function in this answer can't be proven to be path-continuous because it is only defined on $x = 0$,  $x > 0$ and $x < 0$. Absent excluded middle, this is not equivalent to being defined on the entire set of real numbers because trichotomy can't be proven.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield probably not, given [Brouwer's theorem](https://eudml.org/doc/182667) that fully defined functions are continuous.

Comment: This graph is connected but it is not locally connected, anyway, this example shows that it would be interesting to change the definition to require that the graph must be locally connected at (a,f(a)) instead of just connected for f restricted to some neighborhood of a.